# Можно ли при проверке полей формы плагином jQuery Validate добавить класс Error не связанному с формой диву?

Tags: jquery

Можно ли при проверке полей формы плагином jQuery Validate добавить класс Error не связанному с формой диву?

```
$("#header_form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {required: true},
            phone: {required: true}
        },
        messages: {
            name: {required: false},
            phone: {required: false}
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            sendForm(form);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, с помощью методов `highlight/unhighlight`

```
$("#header_form").validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        phone: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        // name: {required: false},
        // phone: {required: false}
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        sendForm(form);
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(".не связанный div").addClass("error");
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(".не связанный div").removeClass("error");
    }
});
```